# How to implement Autocomplete in UISearchbar without UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Need output like this image in my iPhone without using UITableview.Can anyone please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, it's because you don't have a UITableView at the beginning (possibly a map search for instance). Then that item is manually a `UITextField` + a "floating" `UITableView` to show the results.

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to achieve, what you tried so far.

Comment: Why can't you use a tableview? That could be a ui tableview without any separator lines

Comment: please share your code what you done so far

Comment: Can you please give some idea on how to search the data in web service url using UISearchbar like (UISearchdisplaycontroller with UITableview).Here i need to display datas in dropdown like while typing in UISearchbar with some text.

Comment: I have implemented UISearchbar. When i enter the text and click search button am displaying UITableview.Now my requirement is to display data's in dropdown list while searching

Comment: I think you have use TableView for this. This link have custom class that u can use direct  https://github.com/mattott/iOS-AutoComplete-UISearchBar

Comment: please post what you did here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to have a NSArray containing all of the data that you want to provide as potential options for the user. here i am using an NSMutableArray of pastURLs, and every time the user browses to a URL we’ll add it to the array.
Next, you need to create a view to display the URLs that the user can select from. One good way of doing this is just to create a table view below the input field that lists all of the potential options. This table view can appear only when the user is typing data into the text field, and can be hidden the rest of the time.

```
autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;  
[self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
```

Use `UITextFieldDelegate` and implementing the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` protocol.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

  NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
  substring = [substring 
    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
  return YES;
}

- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

  // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
  // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
  [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
  for(NSString *curString in pastUrls) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
      [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
  }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

for more details check : [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values)

Or download demo app: [Demo App](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/AutoCompDemo.zip)

Comment: I have downloaded this app and tried but it is not working :(

Comment: i tried with the above code.its working fine Thank you:)

Comment: How to display the filtered data in UITableview while typing?